# Apply jquery with angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

This is my html code

```
<body ng-app="mainapp">
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="tree" ng-controller="MenuController">
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="menu in menulist">
        <a>{{menu.title}}</a>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="submenu in menu.children"><a href="#">{{submenu.title}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery( '.tree li' ).each(function() {

        if( jQuery( this ).children( 'ul' ).length > 0 ) {
                jQuery( this ).addClass( 'parent' );     
        }
    });

});
```

the each of jquery is not working. If i copy the jquery code and apply on browser console it works.

find fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/rrs_1989/3qeorfbe/

Answer (score 0):

You could simply achieve by using angular `ng-class` directive like `ng-class="{ parent: menu.children.length > 0 }"`

```
<div class="tree" ng-controller="MenuController">
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="menu in menulist">
        <a>{{menu.title}}</a>
        <ul ng-class="{ parent: menu.children.length > 0 }">
            <li ng-repeat="submenu in menu.children"><a href="#">{{submenu.title}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Update**

You will never get `ng-repeat` as angular rendering DOM,  `ng-repeat` does render each items by looping through it. that's take some time. You could track that by when the `ng-reapeat` rendering completed using directive.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('myRepeatDirective', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            //here the ng-repeat ends
            //do some action o DOM manipulation from here
            //you have rendered DOM of ng-repeat
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: @Rakesh does it helped?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking whether the main li has ul children or not (because it always will have), find the ul inside the main li, and check if it has li descendants:

```
if( $(this).find('ul').children('li').length > 0 )
```

Working sample here:
http://codepen.io/ER144/pen/XbbKGz

Watch out, your json in the example in fiddler is corrupt.